# Docker-compose не прокидывает переменные через env_file, хотя через environment они работают

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Собстенно говоря, вопрос в заголовке.

Когда использую в docker-compose environment, - все рабоает.

Когда использую те же переменные в env_file - нет.

DockerEnv.env:

```
#API:
#Database:
DB_HOST=192.168.0.111
DB_PORT=27018
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    restart: always
    build:
      context: core/api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./core/api:/api
    command: ["npm", "run", "start"]
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    env_file:
      - DockerEnv.env
    #environment:
    #  DB_HOST: 192.168.0.111
    #  DB_PORT: 27018
```

Comment: Предоставьте ваш `.env` файл и так же `docker-compose.yml`, есть вероятность, что вы ошиблись в синтаксисе.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/R8SQ0jbH p.s там, где начинается докер файлЮ забыл дописать cat: docker-compose

Comment: Мне кажется, что environment и env_file - не одно и тоже.

Comment: а как вы понимаете, что в случае с envfile у вас не работает (у меня в обоих случаях появляются значения)?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в ковычках, в env file.